# get_the_terms() returning wrong results inside of loop

Tags: theme-development, loop, terms

When I use `get_the_terms()` inside a loop, the whole thing behaves very strangely. Sometimes the terms are included twice or three times and sometimes a post inside of the loop returns only false.

I have used get_the_terms() over and over for the last few years without any problems. So i'm quite confused right now.

It seems like `wp_get_post_terms()` and `wp_get_post_categories()` are getting out the correct data but I would like to know why `get_the_terms()` is behaving this way inside of a loop.

Can someone explain that to me?

[image]

Edit:
Here is my code for the category badges.
Btw: I'm using [sage](https://roots.io/sage/) from roots.io so i'm working with blade templates. It happens on custom queries and default main queries (like: index.php, archive.php etc.)

**index.blade.php**

```php
@if (have_posts())

    @while(have_posts()) @php(the_post())

        @includeFirst(['partials.content-' . get_post_type(), 'partials.content'])

    @endwhile

@endif
```

**partials/content.blade.php**

```php
@php

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

@endphp

@if($terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ))
    <div class="badges">
        @foreach($terms as $term)
            <span class="badge">{!! $term->name !!}</span>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: we need to see your code and the loop, there's not enough information to figure out what's happening

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sorry my bad.. I updated the question. It's a basic normal get_the_terms() function inside of a default loop in index.php or archive.php..

Comment: This must be a caching issue since get_the_terms is a cached version of wp_get_object_terms + the caching of the template files in sage v10 . I'm trying to reach out the roots.io community for this issue. Since i got this resolved with wp_get_post_terms function.